# How to write an async counter, i.e. a counter with sync interface for async code, using only the native Promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, counter

I want to create an object that exposes the following interface:

```
// Create the object that counts to three
const c = counter(3);
// c.finished is a promise that resolves when c.count() is invoked three times
c.finished.then(() => console.log('counted three times!'));

// Somewhere else, c.count() is invoked in async body
setTimeout(() => c.count(), 500);
setTimeout(() => c.count(), 1000);
setTimeout(() => c.count(), 1500);
```

I expect that `c.finished` resolves after 1.5 seconds.

How to write `counter(countTimes)` using only the native `Promise` API?

**Disclosure** I already have [a solution](https://github.com/assister-ai/async-counter/blob/master/index.js) to the above problem, want to know what is the most elegant way to do it.

**Edit**

My original solution was:

```
class AsyncCounter {
  constructor(countTimes) {
    let currentCount = 0;
    this.countTimes = countTimes;
    this.ready = new Promise(resolveReady => {
      this.finished = new Promise(resolveFinished => {
        const count = () => {
          currentCount++;
          if (currentCount >= this.countTimes) {
            resolveFinished();
          }
          return currentCount;
        };
        this.count = () => this.ready.then(() => count());
        resolveReady();
      });
    });
  }
}

const counter = countTimes => new AsyncCounter(countTimes);
```

As suggested by @Bergi and according to [MDN docs for executor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Parameters):

> the executor is called before the Promise constructor even returns the
>   created object

Hence, the `ready` promise in the above solution is not necessary.

Comment: That `ready` promise in your solution makes no sense.

Comment: @Bergi `ready` is there to ensure `c.count` is bound before anyone uses it

Comment: But `bound` is created before anyone sees the object? Also the `ready` promise has exactly the same problem

Comment: I'm not sure, is it guaranteed that body of `ready` promise is invoked before `c` object is returned to the user?

Comment: Yes - and so is the "body" (the executor callback) of the `finished` promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd write

```
function counter(n) {
    let i=0, resolve;
    return {
        count() {
            if (++i == n) resolve();
        },
        finished: new Promise(res => {
            resolve = res;
        })
    };
}
```

Alternatively, instead of putting the `resolve` in an outer variable, you can as well do

```
function counter(n) {
    let i=0;
    const res = {};
    res.finished = new Promise(resolve => { 
        res.count = () => {
            if (++i == n) resolve();
        };
    });
    return res;
}
```

Comment: This looks very elegant, didn't know the "caching the resolve" trick, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd probably write it, however extracting `resolveInternal` into the outer `resolve` variable makes me feel like there must be a better solution. Unfortunately the native `Promise` API doesn't expose any methods to externally resolve a promise object.

```js
function counter(max) {
    let resolve = null;
    const finished = new Promise(resolveInternal => {
        resolve = resolveInternal
    })

    const count = () => {
        if (!--max) resolve()
    }

    return {
        count,
        finished
    }
}

const c = counter(3)

c.finished.then(() => console.log("counted three times!"))

setTimeout(() => c.count(), 500)
setTimeout(() => c.count(), 1000)
setTimeout(() => c.count(), 1500)
```

Comment: "*Unfortunately the native Promise API doesn't expose any methods to externally resolve a promise object.*" - that's because resolving a promise from the outside is kinda unnatural. If those `c.count()` calls wouldn't be sprinkled arbitrarily over code, happening at any time in any order, you'd rather write `Promise.all([delay(500), delay(1000), delay(1500)]).then(() => console.log("all done"))`

Comment: Exactly, I want `counter` to be able to handle "calls sprinkled arbitrarily over code"